# Fisher's test and difference between observed and expected frequencies

Tags: fishers-exact-test, frequency

I was trying to make sense of a statement I came across in a paper. The author states that "The difference between the observed frequency of zero and the expected frequency can now be tested for significance using any statistical test appropriate for contingency tables. For example, the Fisher-Yates exact test yields a probability of error of p = 1.96E-20". Can somebody explain how to use the Fisher-Yates test to determine if the difference between observed and expected frequencies is significant?

Comment: Please add a reference to the paper you quote from.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that the phrasing you quoted tells you the authors don't seem to correctly understand what a p-value is, so it would be prudent to be a little cautious about lending too much credence to their phrasing about what the test tells you either. (Indeed there additional aspects of what is said there that concern me slightly as it might imply that they're doing something that may not be justified.)

Nevertheless there is a straightforward sense in which they're essentially correct on the aspect I think you're asking about, at least for the 2x2 case (and in a looser sense, more generally).

Ideally, it would be great to have the actual table margins but it's possible there's not enough information in the paper to get this.

The discussion below assumes a 2x2 table. In larger tables (Fisher-Yates-Irwin/Freeman-Halton) the discussion is more complicated and the relationship less direct though the large-sample arguments will remain.

---

The Fisher-Yates exact test does not directly compare observed to expected ($O$ to $E$) at all. However in the 2x2 case, what the test does look at (which I will treat as being summarized to a p-value) and an obvious way to measure the distance between $O$ and $E$ will be *extremely* closely related.

Here, when I talk about the difference between observed and expected being "large" or "small", I'll focus on a kind of "standardized" difference in observed and expected, $(O-E)/√V$, where $V=E(1-\hat{\pi}_{i\cdot})(1-\hat{\pi}_{\cdot j})^\top$ (See note [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXEk1.png), Sec 2.4.5, p39).

One reason to do this is that it then shouldn't matter which cell in the table I'm referring to (though it makes sense to do this for other reasons).

In particular (under fixed margins and) given $H_0$, the probability of a table can be obtained from the hypergeometric distribution, which is unimodal around the 'peak' (there may be a case where there's two adjacent modes, but the probability descends either side from there); this mode is generally very close to the mean (where observed would be very close to expected) and frequently exactly at/adjacent to the mean (unless the total count is quite small). As $n$ becomes large, the two will essentially always coincide (in the sense that under the null, the mean of the distribution of observed should typically be within about $1$ of its mode as the sample sample sizes become very large).

In that sense, a low-probability table (under $H_0$) in the Fisher-Yates test corresponds to a large discrepancy in observed vs expected, and higher probability tables will correspond to smaller discrepancy. If you see a low $p$ value you can indeed quite reasonably conclude that the magnitude of $(O-E)/√V$ will be relatively large.

---

**Practical example**

Here's an example I did in R:

Originally the data here had a third column, "Independent" which I omitted to get down to a 2x2 table. It is data from Agresti (ref [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXEk1.png) p.38), used in a help example on the chi-squared test in R (`?chisq.test`).

```
 M[,c(1,3)]
      party
gender Democrat Republican
     F      762        468
     M      484        477
```

So now we imagine we want to look at the relationship between the Fisher-Yates p-value and the size of the O vs E discrepancy $| (O-E)/√V |$ for tables with the same margins.

So we sample a bunch of tables at random under $H_0$, conditioning on the margins (as the Fisher-Yates test does) and look at the relationship between the p-value in the Fisher-Yates test and the absolute value of $(O-E)/√V$,
i.e. $|(O-E)/√V|$.

```
 r=rowSums(M[,c(1,3)])             # get row totals
 c=colSums(M[,c(1,3)])             # get col totals
 n=1000
 tables=r2dtable(n,r,c)            # sample 1000 tables at random with the 
                                   # same margins under independence.
 f=function(x) chisq.test(x)$stdres[1,1]  # get (O-E)/√V for one cell . . .
 oeres=sapply(tables,f)            #  ...  for each table
 f2=function(x) fisher.test(x)$p.value  # get F-Y p-value
 p=sapply(tables,f2)               #  .... for each table
 print(cor(p,abs(oeres),method="kendall"),d=3) # get the Kendall correlation
[1] -1
```

As you see, the two are essentially perfectly negatively related - when one goes up, the other goes down (the actual correlation was about -0.999992, because there were a few cases where the rank of the p-value and that of  $|(O-E)/√V |$ did not align perfectly. See note [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9PpN.png)).

Here's the plot of the absolute standardized residuals $|O-E|/\sqrt{V}$ vs the Fisher-Yates p-value:

[image: Plot of absolute standardized residuals vs Fisher=Yates p value]

The darker levels of grey in the plotted values indicates greater multiplicity of coincident points.

This looks like the relationship is monotonic, but as we saw from the Kendall correlation, it wasn't perfectly monotonic. The slight discrepancy occurs in a few observations in the region above and to the left of the red lines in the top left corner of the plot above:

[image: Zooming in on top left section of the previous plot]

The three brown ovals indicate all the places where the order of $p$ and the order of $|(O-E)/√V|$ are not in inverse order, but even zoomed in like this, it is very hard to spot that the $|(O-E)/√V|$ values are not quite equal there, but actually slightly increasing as we move right within each oval.

*Why did I use Kendall tau in particular?* I used that measure because it is the proportion of times values move in the same direction minus the proportion of times the values move in opposite direction; i.e. it relates most directly to having the same ordering.

Similar results are seen with other data.

---

So in 2x2 tables, low p-values correspond to large discrepancy in observed vs expected, *very nearly* always.

When you have a very small p-value (implying the total table $n$ will not be very small), the set of tables contributing their probability under $H_0$ to the p-value will have essentially a perfect association in the ordering of  $|O-E|/√V$  and $p$ (smaller $p$ means larger magnitude of  $(O-E)/√V$)

In short, these observed-expected discrepancies and the Fisher-Yates test are *almost perfectly* equivalent in the 2x2 case, at least as long the table isn't quite small (perhaps closer still if you use the chi-squared statistic as the basis of an exact test). It's quite safe to talk about $O$ and $E$ being discrepant when you get a very small p-value (see note [3]).

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXEk1.png):  Agresti, A. (2007).  An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis, 2nd ed.
New York: John Wiley & Sons.  Page 38.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9PpN.png): In this example it  looks like the relationship is monotonic but not strictly monotonic; there are a handful of rank-disagreements, even though there's no discernable reversals of direction in the $|(O-E)/√V|$ vs $p$ plot itself; the effect is very small. (See note [4])

[3]: you won't get small p-values with very small-n tables

[4]: **Aside, not related to the current question**: A  discrepancy in the places where the ties of $p$ vs those of $|(O-E)/√V|$ and even of their ordering can be useful. In smaller tables, one of the serious problems with any exact test, whether Fisher-Yates-Irwin or one based on say the Pearson chi-squared or the G-test, or whatever else you like, is a lack of available significance levels (due to the discreteness; i.e. "tied" values of the statistic). If two statistics have somewhat different order, or even different sets of ties, you can combine statistics (using one as your main statistic and using the other to help break ties in the first) to get more available significance levels. This will increase test power (by letting you get closer to the specified alpha) without changing the interpretation of the test statistic (it just lets you split some of the tied cases).  If you can find a third statistic that has its ties in different places again, you can do even better, using it to break ties in the combined test and so (perhaps) gaining a little better power still.

In a table as large-n as this one the advantage is at extremely small p-values but in smaller tables (where it matters more) they may occur at values closer to where it may matter for practical choices of significance level.